# Facebook auth method in Cocoa can this be improved?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, cocoa

This is how i currently receive my access_token from facebook, currently looking at creating a simple Facebook client for mac.

```
  NSString *clientId = @"********";
  NSString *scope = @"read_stream";

  NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
                         "client_id=%@"
                         "&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"
                         "&scope=%@"
                         "&response_type=token", clientId, scope];

    NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES] autorelease];

    [req release];
```

Then i pickup the didReceiveResponse delegate:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse: (NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSString *urlString = [[response URL] absoluteString];

    int accessTokenStartPosition = [urlString rangeOfString:@"access_token="].location + 13;
    int accessTokenEndPosition   = [urlString rangeOfString:@"&"].location;

    NSRange accessTokenRange = NSMakeRange(accessTokenStartPosition, accessTokenEndPosition - accessTokenStartPosition);
    NSString *accessToken = [urlString substringWithRange: accessTokenRange];

    int expiryStartPosition = [urlString rangeOfString:@"expires_in="].location + 11;
    int expiryEndPosition   = urlString.length;

    NSRange expiryRange = NSMakeRange(expiryStartPosition, expiryEndPosition - expiryStartPosition);
    NSString *expiryTime = [urlString substringWithRange: expiryRange];

    NSLog(@"Test: %@", accessToken);
    NSLog(@"Test: %@", expiryTime);
}
```

Not sure if this is the best method and would rather not use the Facebook SDK for iOS, is there a better method or am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use FBGraph API provided by Facebook for IOS, which is very handy and convenient to use, you can get complete tutorial of new oAuth 2.0 Based version of FBGraph API, [Get the tutorial here](http://www.capturetheconversation.com/best-practices/iphone-facebook-oauth-2-0-and-the-graph-api-a-tutorial-part-2)